# custom UISlider for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios4

I am developing an application for iPad which needs to select  a particular interval of data in a UISlider.The slider should have two slider buttons ,also the control should allow movement of interval i.e area between two slider buttons to select some other interval of data.Is there any custom UI slider available to handle this.Looking forward for your ideas…
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Two ways for creating UISlider

**First way**

Create one UISlider from Programming.

Now you can set Images on it as you want.

Here is the code for putting images on UISlider..

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0)];
[slider setColorPicker:colorPicker];
[slider setUseCustomSlider:NO];

[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbSlider.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbSlider.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey_slide.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[slider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_slide.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

**Another Way for creating Custom Slider**

Now create one More slider with Two images only via UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Add two images on it. One is like strip and another one is like thumb image.

Here is the code.

Create Slider first..

```
UIImageView *imageback = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 47)] autorelease];
imageback.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"strip.png"];
imageback.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[sliderView addSubview:imageback];

sliderImg = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(147.5, 27, 25, 25)] autorelease];
sliderImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
sliderImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"];
sliderImg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
sliderImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[sliderView addSubview:sliderImg];
```

Now Apply UIPanGestureRecognizer to dot image..

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureImg = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetectedSlider:)];
[sliderImg addGestureRecognizer:panGestureImg];
[panGestureImg release];
```

**Pan Gesture Method.**

```
-(void)panDetectedSlider:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    if ([panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        //Start
    }
    else if([panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        //Change
        CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:sliderImg];
        CGPoint imageViewPosition = sliderImg.center;
        imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
        sliderImg.center = imageViewPosition;
        [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:sliderImg];
    }
    else if([panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || [panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed || [panRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        //End
    }
}
```